# Efeitos css não funcionam apos importados na ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Bom dia. 
Tenho uma página html, com alguns efeitos de animação. A mesma funciona perfeita mente. Porém ao importar o body da página com ng-view (angularjs) as animações não são mais executadas.

Se eu colar o conteúdo que esta sendo importado pra dentro de ng-view fora dele. As animações funcionam perfeitamente.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?
Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Boa noite amigo, esses efeitos CSS foi você mesmo que contruiu ? pois em alguns frameworks como o Material Design Lite, você deve fazer um  `componentHandler.upgradeElement(element);` para registrá-lo.